# Virtualbox - Configuration error: Querying "UUID" failed (VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND)

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I am installing hackintosh in virtualbox on ubuntu, but when I try to start, I get above error.

Here are some more details,

```
Result Code:   NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to install Sierra, but now I downloaded `OSX Mavericks` and it worked fine.

If you got `Error loading drivers` while boot Go to `System -> Motherboard` and Disable `Enable EFI (Special OSes Only)`.

Answer (score 0):

its because system try to reach some resources (anything connected to mother board) and it fails, so the vm restarts.
solution is changing the mindset:
remember you are tunning a device that will share your host devices resources so dont go full settings. if you are getting this error try to preallocate RAM/ROM and set the graphics and cpu core usages to minimal requirements of your machines duty. then you wont see that error again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).