# Unknown configuration value '/GetKeyFromRealSMdC'

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, macosx

I've tried to install Mac OS on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, i followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8otPMUL08g&t=262s&ab_channel=LinesofCode).

With this input,

Commands for Virtualbox:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "macOS Monterey tutorial" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff
VBoxManage setextradata "macOS Monterey tutorial" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3"
VBoxManage setextradata "macOS Monterey tutorial" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"
VBoxManage setextradata "macOS Monterey tutorial" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" "Iloveapple"
VBoxManage setextradata "macOS Monterey tutorial" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey" "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"
VBoxManage setextradata "macOS Monterey tutorial" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC" 1
VBoxManage setextradata "macOS Monterey tutorial" "VBoxInternal/TM/TSCMode" "RealTSCOffset"
```

Then when i tried to start it show this error:

```
Unknown configuration value '/GetKeyFromRealSMdC' found in the configuration of smc instance #0 (VERR_CFGM_CONFIG_UNKNOWN_VALUE).
```

Result Code:

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component:
ConsoleWrap
Interface:
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

How i can solve it?

Comment: Virtualizing MacOS is a legal gray area because not allowed by its own terms of service. In some SE sites like superuser.com it's explicitly off-topic. It should be here as well.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't think that's relevant, because OP doesn't ask help in virtualizing MacOS, they instead ask help related to VirtualBox configuration. In terms of a proof: replace MacOS with Windows or Linux in that question, that would change nothing. OP has simply mistyped an option, and would get the error disregarding the guest OS.

Answer (score 2):

You mistyped one of the options. Note that you have `GetKeyFromRealSMC` in your list of commands for VB, however the error talks instead about `GetKeyFromRealSMdC`

To fix that remove the wrong configuration value. It's doable either by editing the VM config manually, or by repeating the `setextradata` command *but omitting the value at the end*. E.g.:

```haskell
VBoxManage setextradata "macOS Monterey tutorial" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMdC"
```

Comment: Now i see this error: 
Configuration error: Querying "UUID" failed (VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND).

Comment: @Userubuntu1 that's an unrelated error. If you search for it in your favorite search engine, you'll find various topics on the matter, related to running MacOS in VB specifically. You might start with [the answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967625/virtualbox-configuration-error-querying-uuid-failed-verr-cfgm-value-not-fo), though it has no upvotes, but see if it works for you. If it doesn't, however you'll find a solution, consider writing your own answer there and ping me up, I'll upvote it.